# Expose endpoint in HTTP over HTTPS in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my Spring Boot app in which I've implemented Spring Security, I am currently running it on HTTPS but I want to expose a certain actuator endpoint on HTTP in order to Prometheus gets metrics from. Every tutorial I've found so far, has only the opposite. I know that the below code in my Main Class redirects all HTTP traffic to HTTPS but since I've already achieved that, I tried if I could modify the code for the opposite result only to no avail.

Then, I tried to check if somehow I could achieve my goal with,

```
management.server.ssl.enabled=false
management.server.port=8081
```

but I couldn't get any results in my browser in exposing Prometheus metrics, since for some reason the port isn't accesible.

So is it possible to have my whole application on HTTPS as it is right now, and redirect - expose just one Get Mapping mathod on HTTP? Just for testing purposes I have the Greeting Method below, in order to make my implementations.

**Rest Controller Class (For Test Purposes)**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot.control.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Sample {

    @GetMapping(value = "/greeting")
    public String greeting() {
        return "I am working with both HTTP and HTTPS";
    }
}
```

**Security Config Class**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot.authentication.security;

import com.andrekreou.iot.authentication.user.ApplicationUserService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig {

    private final ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .requiresChannel()
                    .antMatchers("/greeting","/actuator/prometheus")
                    .requiresInsecure()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**","/register*","/login","/registration","/registration-complete","/greeting").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/",true)
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID","Idea-2e8e7cee")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(applicationUserService);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot;

import io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityCollection;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class IotApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IotApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new TimedAspect(registry);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector redirectConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

**Application.properties**

```
#Server properties for HTTPS configuration
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:local-ssl.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=<password>
server.ssl.key-alias=local_ssl
server.port=8443
```

Comment: `collection.addPattern("/*")`

Comment: @BoristheSpider I suppose that this is the place that I should place my URL? With the asterisk that means that the whole traffic will be executed? Sorry I am completely new to this!!!

Comment: @Vel_More could you update your question with links to your tutorials, please? It'd be more informative and descriptive. Thank you.